# issue in calling .ashx page

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ThumbNailImage.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("ImageID")  %>' />
```

hi this is  how my
 directory  structure  looks

```
        1:  admin
                 -->ThumbNailImage.ashx page 
        2:  comman
                  -->default.aspx page
```

1: here  from default.aspx page i am trying to call  my  ThumbNailImage.ashx 
 here  my  break point is not  hitting the page ThumbNailImage.ashx 
 and even  images  are not  shown in  gridview [and in this page  default.aspx  i even have  flash script is there anything  to do with it]

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "admin/ThumbNailImage.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("ImageID")  %>' />
```

tried even like this

2:   but the pages  which is under admin folder  are  able  to display the image  what is the issue  is it the  directory structure

any help  would be great 
thank  you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If ThumbnailImage.ashx is in the admin folder, your ImageUrls should be all be using "~/admin/ThumbNailImage.ashx".

Neither of the two code samples you've provided are using that URL, but the first one works because you're (presumably) calling it from the context of another page in the admin folder.  The second one doesn't work because the relative URL you've specified is pointing to an admin subfolder *inside* the common folder, which doesn't exist.  Using ~ at the beginning of the URL tells ASP.NET to resolve this URL relative to the root of your application, so it's correct no matter the context in which it's being used.

Comment: thank  you Mike Powell

 the  final  code  that made  work 
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/admin/ThumbNailImage.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("ImageID")  %>' />

Answer (score 0):

Have you folder / membership permissions on the Admin folder?

If so, does the currently logged in user, for which the images are not displaying, have rights to that folder?

Take it out of Admin maybe?

Edit - Or i missed the path mistake, check Mikes post. :)